# PhidgetRFID chip: How to detect tags

Tags: java, nfc

I have a PhidgetRFID chip (P/N:1023, version 205). I am trying to make a simple program in order to detect tags and show their unique id number. I found the following source code from its manufacturer website

```
import com.phidgets.*;
import com.phidgets.event.*;

public class RFIDExample
{
    public static final void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        RFIDPhidget rfid;

        System.out.println(Phidget.getLibraryVersion());

        rfid = new RFIDPhidget();
        rfid.addAttachListener(new AttachListener() {
            public void attached(AttachEvent ae)
            {
                try
                {
                    ((RFIDPhidget)ae.getSource()).setAntennaOn(true);
                    ((RFIDPhidget)ae.getSource()).setLEDOn(true);
                }
                catch (PhidgetException ex) { }
                System.out.println("attachment of " + ae);
            }
        });
        rfid.addDetachListener(new DetachListener() {
            public void detached(DetachEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("detachment of " + ae);
            }
        });
        rfid.addErrorListener(new ErrorListener() {
            public void error(ErrorEvent ee) {
                System.out.println("error event for " + ee);
            }
        });
        rfid.addTagGainListener(new TagGainListener()
        {
            public void tagGained(TagGainEvent oe)
            {
                System.out.println("Tag Gained: " +oe.getValue() + " (Proto:"+ oe.getProtocol()+")");
            }
        });
        rfid.addTagLossListener(new TagLossListener()
        {
            public void tagLost(TagLossEvent oe)
            {
                System.out.println(oe);
            }
        });
        rfid.addOutputChangeListener(new OutputChangeListener()
        {
            public void outputChanged(OutputChangeEvent oe)
            {
                System.out.println(oe);
            }
        });

        rfid.openAny();
        System.out.println("waiting for RFID attachment...");
        rfid.waitForAttachment(30000);

        System.out.println("Serial: " + rfid.getSerialNumber());
        System.out.println("Outputs: " + rfid.getOutputCount());

        }
    }
```

but i received the following error:

*Phidget21 - Version 2.1.8 - Built Feb 22 2016 11:45:54
waiting for RFID attachment...
Exception in thread "main" PhidgetException 13 (Given timeout has been exceeded.)
    at com.phidgets.Phidget.waitForAttachment(Native Method)
    at RFIDExample.main(RFIDExample.java:58)*

What i have alredy tried, is to increase timer but problem didn't solve.
I tried to use the manufacturer's application for my RFID chip and it worked, it detcted tags properly. But i need to use source code and not the ready application.

Any help would be very useful!
Thank you in advance! :)

BR,
Loukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was that i was trying to execute the code and i had the ready application open at the same time.

Now it works properly.

Problem solved.